# Postman-generated cUrl and Swift codes result in status 415, but when running the same from postman itself I get 400 (which is correct)

Tags: ios, asp.net-mvc, curl, postman, x-www-form-urlencoded

I need to post a single key-value pair from a Swift iOS app using form-data.
The Postman example that was provided by the back-end developer works:

The Postman Body tab shows "SelectedCreditCard" under "KEY" and "34" under "VALUE"

The method is POST.

The Postman Headers tab shows "Content-Type" under KEY and "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" under VALUE, and an additional authorization token header.

When running from Postman I get status 400 with a JSON body that contains an "Invalid credit card" warning. This is the expected result.

When implementing this in Swift I received 415 (media not supported). I pasted the curl code generated by Postman to the Mac command line, just to see how it looks, and to my surprise I got the same result as in the iOS App.

The curl code:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://stg.xxx.com/api/xxx/SavePaymentInfo' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxx' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--form 'SelectedCreditCard=34'
```

The curl result:

```
    {"$type":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ProblemDetails,
     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core",
    "type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13",
"title":"Unsupported Media Type",
    "status":415,
    "traceId":"0HLTFOL7EGBUA:00000007"}%
```

I have also tried the generated Objective C code provided by Postman and the generated Swift code, and in all cases the result is 415. The only case in which I get the correct result (400 with an invalid card warning) is when running the post directly from Postman itself. I wonder what causes this gap.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: in curl, instead of "Content-Type", the header name should be  "Accept" (no need to specify a Content-Type)